# Can't install Python library gnureadline on Fedora 22

Tags: python, pip, fedora

On Fedora 22, `pip install gnureadline` fails with error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the gnureadline binary from package control:

`sudo yum install readline-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Works after `yum install readline-devel`

Provided you have `libxml-devel`,`libxlst-devel`, and `python-devel` installed already